# Make PNG sprites in PIL but want to preserve alpha channel

Tags: python, image, image-processing, png, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a script to grab a bunch of favicons, convert them to png and make a single sprite image out of all of them.

The helpful g.etfv.co will detect and convert favicons in PNG format, and I'm using PIL to montage the images into a sprite sheet.

It all works fine except I seem to lose the alpha transparency channel when I do this.

<s>Resulting image from the below script: [image]. Note the black areas that are supposed to be transparent.</s>

**Update:** Now creating image in mode 'RGBA' rather than 'RGB'. Resulting image is now only *partially* borked: [image]. OKCupid's icon looks correct but stackoverflow's is still losing the alpha channel.

**Update:** I note that it so happens that images it messes up on it reports as being RGB (not RGBA) prior to conversion.

```
>>> print url, img.getbands()
http://stackoverflow.com/ ('R', 'G', 'B')
http://www.google.com/ ('R', 'G', 'B')
http://blog.okcupid.com/ ('R', 'G', 'B', 'A')
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import urllib
import PIL.Image
import StringIO

favicon_base = 'http://g.etfv.co/'

icons = """
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://www.google.com/
http://blog.okcupid.com/
"""

icons = [icon.strip() for icon in icons.strip().splitlines()]

left = 0
right = 16
upper = 0
lower = 16

inew = PIL.Image.new('RGBA',(len(icons)*16,16))

for url in icons:
    favicon = urllib.urlopen(favicon_base + urllib.quote(url) + '?defaulticon=lightpng').read()

    img = PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(favicon))
    img = img.convert('RGBA')

    bbox = (left, upper, right, lower)
    inew.paste(img, bbox, img)

    left += 16
    right += 16


inew.save(open('blah.png', 'wb'), 'png', optimize=1)
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

The result image `inew` has no alpha chanel.

UPDATE:

try

```
inew = PIL.Image.new('RGBA',(len(icons)*16,16))
```

Comment: So, should he be creating it with `inew = PIL.Image.new('RGBA',(len(icons)*16,16))` or what?

Comment: just tried that, strangely it fixes the okcupid icon only but stackoverflow's remains borked. I'll update the question with that info